# OdbcConnection does not support parallel transactions

Tags: vb.net, parallel-processing, odbc

I am using Visual Studio 2010 (VB.Net). I am using following code which is throwing this error:

> OdbcConnection does not support parallel transactions

```
try
tran = conn.begintransaction(isolationlevel.readcommitted)
cmd1.connection = conn
cmd1.transaction = tran
cmd1.executenonquery()
catch ex as exception
tran.rollback()
endtry

try
cmd2.connection = conn
cmd2.transaction = tran
cmd.executenonquery()
catch ex as exception
tran.rollback()
endtry

tran.commit()
```

I don't understand where is the problem?

Comment: Lan Kemp , the error is 'OdbcConnection does not support parallel transactions' :(

Comment: Add `tran.commit()` after first `endtry` ;).

Comment: Thanks for reply shA.t , I hv tried tran.commit  after first endtry but then i get another error says - This odbc transactoin has completed; it is no longer usable. :(((( whats happening ?

Comment: shA.t ,, Also please note this code running fine in development server (test server) but when generates this error on LiveServer.